# Django. Проблема отправки файлов с сервера ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

У меня есть список постов. У каждого поста есть фотографии. При нажатии на пост, я по ajax получаю информацию по постам. Я хочу сделать форму для изменения существующих фотографий из поста. Как по ajax получить изображения с сервера для изменения(удаление существующего или добавление новой фотографии).

Так отправляю ответ на запрос.

Как сделать превью существующих фотографий с возможностью удаления или добавления новой?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4t13.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2DiY.png

Comment: Каким образом вы хотите редактировать изображения через input?

Comment: я хотел сделать превью существующих изображений на сервере с возможностью добавления или удаления фотографий. Как правильно это сделать не понимаю. Точнее как получить изображения через ajax

Comment: Для превью изображения вам input не нужен. Сделайте просто через тег img.

Comment: а добавление нового изображения. Если выведу в img, и добавлю новое изображение, как это отправить на сервер вместе?

Comment: Зачем вместе отправлять? Отправляйте на сервер только новые добавленные изображения. Добавлять можно через input.